Evaluate $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(x)\ln\left ( \frac{1-x}{1+x} \right ) }{\sqrt{x(1-x^2)} }\text{d}x$
In an attempt to solve the following hypergeometric series, which is originated from this question, I got the integral:
$$
\,_4F_3\left ( \frac14,\frac14,\frac12,\frac12;1,\frac54,\frac54;1 \right )
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 
\frac{\left ( \frac12 \right )^2_n }{(1)_n^2}\frac{1}{\left ( 4n+1 \right )^2 }=\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^4 }{64\pi}  
+\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^2 }{4\sqrt{2}\pi^{5/2} } 
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(x)\ln\left ( \frac{1-x}{1+x}  \right ) }{\sqrt{x(1-x^2)} }\text{d}x.
$$
Differentiating Euler beta function gives
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln\left ( x \right )
\ln\left ( 1-x^2 \right )  }{\sqrt{x\left ( 1-x^2 \right ) } }
\text{d} x
=\frac{1}{4} \left.\frac{\partial^2}{\partial s\partial t} 
\operatorname{B}\left ( s+\frac{1}{4},t+\frac12  \right ) 
\right|_{s=0,t=0}
=\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^2 }{8\sqrt{2\pi} } 
\left ( 16G-\pi^2-2\pi\ln(2) \right ).
$$
But this does not work for our case. We could also expand the logarithm part to derive a twisted hypergeometric series(involving harmonic numbers) but eventually come out a mess. Explicitly we say
$$
\int_{0}^{1} 
\frac{\ln(x)\ln(1-x)}{\sqrt{x\left ( 1-x^2 \right ) } } \text{d}x
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 
\frac{\left ( \frac{1}{2}  \right )_n }{n!} 
\left ( \frac{4}{(4n+1)^2}H_{2n+\frac12} 
-\frac{2}{4n+1}\psi^{(1)}\left ( 2n+\frac32 \right )   \right ),
$$
where $H_n=\gamma+\psi^{(0)}(n+1)$ are generalized harmonic numbers, $\psi^{(0)},\psi^{(1)}$ denote digamma and trigamma function respectively. It is not welcomed so I wonder whether a beautiful closed-form exists.
And I am thankful for being given invaluable suggestions and insights.

Personal Attitudes Towards the Existence of a Closed-form.
Closed-forms of the corresponding hypergeometric $L$-values $L(s)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 
\frac{\left ( 1/2\right )^2_n }{(1)_n^2}\frac{1}{\left ( 4n+1 \right )^s }$ at odd integers are known. For instance
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left ( \frac12 \right )_n^2 }{(1)_n^2}
\frac{1}{\left ( 4n+1 \right )^{5} }  
=\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^4 }{32\pi^2} 
\left ( G^2+\beta(4) \right ) .
$$
But the cases for even integers remain elusive, just $\zeta(2),\zeta(3)$ alike. Possibly we couldn't express it through conventional mathmatical constants.

Update 1.
By standard hypergeometric transformation, we have an equivalent expression.
$$
\,_4F_3\left ( \frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4} ,\frac{1}{2} ,
\frac12;1,\frac54,\frac54;1  \right ) 
=\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac{1}{4}  \right )^4 }{32\pi} 
-\frac{1}{\pi}\,_4F_3\left ( \left \{ 1 \right \}_4;
\left \{ \frac32 \right \}_3;1   \right ).
$$
Update 2. Making use of the following identity,
$$
K\left ( \sqrt{1-x}  \right ) 
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}
\frac{\left ( \frac12 \right )_n^2}{(1)_n^2} 
x^n\left ( -\frac12\ln(x)-2\left (  H_{2n}-H_n-\ln(2)\right )  \right ),\quad x\in(0,1],
$$
one have
$$
\frac{1}{8} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{K\left ( \sqrt{1-x}  \right ) }{x^{3/4}}
\text{d} x=\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^4 }{32\pi} 
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left ( \frac12\right )_n^2}{(1)_n^2}
\frac{1}{\left ( 4n+1 \right )^2 }  
-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left ( \frac12\right )_n^2}{(1)_n^2} \frac{H_{2n}-H_{n}-\ln(2)}{4n+1}.
$$
Note that two Fourier-Legendre expansions are given by
$$\small
\frac{\ln\left ( x(1-x) \right ) }{\sqrt{x(1-x)} } 
=-2\pi\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 
\frac{\left ( \frac12\right )_n^2}{(1)_n^2}(4n+1)\left ( H_{2n}+2\ln(2) \right )
P_{2n}(2x-1),\qquad K\left ( \sqrt{x}  \right ) 
=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n+1}P_n(2x-1).
$$
Therefore it's possible to prove $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 
\frac{\left ( 1/2\right )_n^2}{(1)_n^2}\frac{H_{2n}}{4n+1}
= \frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac{1}{4}  \right )^4 }{32\pi^2}
(\pi-4\ln(2))$, and we leave the last formulation here.
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 
\frac{\left ( \frac12 \right )^2_n }{(1)_n^2\left ( 4n+1 \right ) }
\left ( H_n+\frac{1}{4n+1}  \right )  
=\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^4}{16\pi^2} 
\left ( \pi-3\ln(2) \right ).
$$

If you expand $\log \left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)$ around $x=0$, the integrals are simple but the infinite sum ?? The asymptotics of the summand is nice

This is not an answer but it is too long for comments.
$$I=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log(x)\log\left ( \frac{1-x}{1+x} \right ) }{\sqrt{x(1-x^2)} }\,dx$$
Writing
\begin{aligned}
\log\left ( \frac{1-x}{1+x} \right )&=-2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\\
J_n&=\int_0^1 x^{2n+1}\,\frac{\log(x) }{\sqrt{x(1-x^2)} }\,dx\\
J_n&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{4}\,\frac{\Gamma
   \left(n+\frac{3}{4}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(n+\frac{5}{4}\right)}\,  \left(H_{n-\frac{1}{4}}-H_{n+\frac{1}{4}}\right)\\
I&=-\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma
   \left(n+\frac{3}{4}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(n+\frac{5}{4}\right)}\,\frac{\left(H_{n-\frac{1}{4}}-H_{n+\frac{1}{4}}\right) }{2n+1}
\end{aligned}
If $a_n$ is the summand
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1-\frac{5}{2 n}+\frac{45}{8
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ shows a slow convergence of the summation.
Now, could we use the fact that
$$a_n=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{8 n^{5/2}}\,\Bigg(1-\frac{5}{4 n}+\frac{65}{64n^2}-\frac{165}{256n^3}+\frac{2829}{8192n^4}+
O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)\Bigg)$$ and write
$$I=\frac{(18402527372-4806289215 \pi ) \sqrt{\pi }\, \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}{6923211750\,
   \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)}+\sum_{n=5}^\infty a_n$$ where will appear a linear combination of $\zeta \left(\frac{2m+1}{2}\right)$.
Using the above expansion, converted to decimals, this would give $I=\color{red}{1.156399}38$
Using the expansion to $O\left(\frac{1}{n^{25}}\right)$ would give
$I=\color{red}{1.15639909485698}03$
